# Why is swagger not working in chrome or firefox?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, swagger

Swagger out of the box is only working on IE 11 for my local instance. Chrome and Firefox are displaying a "site can't be reached" error. I have confirmed my firewall is not the culprit. I am running .NET framework 4.8. Swashbuckle version 5.6.0.
I'm not sure where else to look for troubleshooting. Thoughts?

Comment: Swagger doesn't require IE 11. On the contrary, I'm not sure if it *works* with IE 11, or the HTML appears mangled because it uses features that weren't available 7 years ago. `site can't be reached` is a networking message, so the *firewall* or proxy is quite possibly the culprit. Does your intranet use a proxy perhaps? IE 11 may have picked it up from a domain policy, while Chrome and Firefox didn't

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
Confirmed, it does indeed work in IE 11. 
Confirmed Chrome and FF are both allowed public and private access via the firewall. 
Also, no proxy needed.. I'm working on my home network.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that you have a network error. There's no other usable information beyond that. Are you trying to connect to an external service? Or a a web api project? Does your site run to begin with?

Comment: I understand, this is frustrating to me because there's not much to go on besides a generic network issue. To your questions.. 
My swagger is implemented in a web api project. It does compile, it does run. As I said, everything runs perfectly in IE 11. It's not an external service, everything is local on my machine at this moment.

Comment: `It does compile, it does run.` but is it running when you use Chrome? Forget about IE 11. You aren't the first developer to use Swagger in the last 7 years. *VERY* few developers would even try to use IE 11 to connect to a Swagger endpoint by now. The web service doesn't "run in IE11". IE 11 is a browser that tries to connect to that already running service. How did you try to use IE11 in the first place? Did you configure the project to use IE11 while debugging perhaps? Which means that closing IE11 will also stop the debugger?

Comment: To clarify.. the web app and api projects run fine in all browsers. Navigating to localhost:<port>/swagger/ui/index is where I run into issues. IE came into the picture purely out of my own curiosity when I noticed chrome and FF weren't working. So the issues is purely when navigating to swagger ui

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable CORS support -
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#cors-support